# Unexpected lighting behavior in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

I'm using ChartElementData["CylindricalSector3D"] to generate graphics representing a series of stacked concentric rings (4 rings, 3 layers high).  I'm looking to highlight sections of this via variable opacities, so I've set it up as a function f[a,b,c,{d1,d2,d3,d4},{e1,e2,e3}]; a/b/c sets up some basic parameters, dn are the opacities of the rings, and en are the opacities of the layers.

Also, since "CylindricalSector3D" natively draws a vertical face that would have visible edges, I've generated new outlines using cylinders with FaceForm[None].  Code:

```
rads2[bore_] := 0.5*{{30.35 + 1.75*bore, 37.1}, {18.95 + 1.75*bore, 30.35 - 1.75*bore}, {7.3 + 0.8*bore, 18.95 - 1.75*bore}, {0, 7.3 - 0.8*bore}};
hts2 = {5.7, 6.4, 6.2};
faceHeights[zSep_, heights_, zoffset_] := 0.5*heights*{-1, 1} + 0.5*zoffset*(6.4 + heights + 2*zSep)*{1, 1};

cols2 = {Darker[Purple, 0.5], Blue, Darker[Green, 0.7], Darker[Orange, 0.3]};
lght[color_, blending_] := {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0.4]}, {"Directional", Blend[{GrayLevel[0.1], color}, blending], {0, 0, 1}}};

opcts[opH_, opV_] := Opacity[0.15 + 0.85*opH*opV];
segments[rad_, zSep_, opH_, opV_, heights_, zoffset_] := {opcts[opH, opV], EdgeForm[None], ChartElementData["CylindricalSector3D"][{{0, 2 \[Pi]}, rad, faceHeights[zSep, heights, zoffset]}, 0]};
edges[i_, j_, bore_, zSep_, opH_, opV_, heights_, zoffset_] := {FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.003], opcts[opH, opV]]], Map[Cylinder[{{0, 0, faceHeights[zSep, heights, zoffset][[1]]},{0, 0, faceHeights[zSep, heights, zoffset][[2]]}}, #] &, rads2[bore][[i]]]};
```

First block is basic geometric setup.  The second one defines my custom lighting: I'm highlighting the different rings by having them lit from above by different colors.  The third generates individual segment and edges, which will be combined with Table to form the full image.

Both the segments and outlines seem to work great, independently:

```
allsegments[bore_, zSep_, coloring_, opacHoriz_, opacVert_] :=  Graphics3D[Table[{Lighting -> lght[cols2[[i]], coloring], segments[rads2[bore][[i]], zSep, opacHoriz[[i]], opacVert[[j]], hts2[[j]], j - 2]}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}], Boxed -> False, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}];
alledges[bore_, zSep_, coloring_, opacHoriz_, opacVert_] := Graphics3D[Table[{edges[i, j, bore, zSep, opacHoriz[[i]], opacVert[[j]], hts2[[j]], j - 2]}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}], Boxed -> False, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}];

opts = Transpose@{
{0, 0, 0, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{0.5, 0.5*10, 0.5, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{1, 10, 1, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}},
{1, 10, 1, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}},
{1, 10, 1, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}},
{1, 10, 1, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}},
{1, 10, 1, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}},
{1, 10, 1, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}},
{1, 10, 1, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}},
{1, 10, 1, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}
};
GraphicsRow[MapThread[allsegments, opts], ImageSize -> 1300]
GraphicsRow[MapThread[alledges, opts], ImageSize -> 1300]
```

[image]

However, when I try to combine them into a single Graphics3D object, most of my highlighting seems to be affected. This seems surprising since both are populated by identical Tables in the preceding example, and I just grouped the arguments together.

```
combinedFeats[bore_, zSep_, coloring_, opacHoriz_, opacVert_] := Graphics3D[Table[{Lighting -> lght[cols2[[i]], coloring], segments[rads2[bore][[i]], zSep, opacHoriz[[i]], opacVert[[j]], hts2[[j]], j - 2], edges[i, j, bore, zSep, opacHoriz[[i]], opacVert[[j]], hts2[[j]], j - 2]}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}], Boxed -> False, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}];
GraphicsRow[MapThread[combinedFeats, opts], ImageSize -> 1300]
```

[image]

Interestingly, the appropriate lighting is actually still present, but apparently applied from the bottom:

```
GraphicsRow[Table[Show[combinedFeats[1, 10, 1, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}], ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, vpz}], {vpz, {2, 0, -2}}], ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Further, even though the compiled segments and outlines are generated properly (first image), trying to combine these with Show yields similar (but different) issues:

```
combinedImgs[bore_, zSep_, coloring_, opacHoriz_, opacVert_] := Show[{allsegments[bore, zSep, coloring, opacHoriz, opacVert], alledges[bore, zSep, coloring, opacHoriz, opacVert]}, Boxed -> False];
GraphicsRow[MapThread[combinedImgs, opts], ImageSize -> 1300]
```

[image]

Normally I wouldn't be surprised to have to flesh out some unwanted interaction to lighting/camera settings when interleaving the segments and edges (compared to using them together, but that obviously doesn't explain the issue that appears with show.

Note:

- I was able to come up with a refreshingly simple (if not entirely
  satisfying) workaround that was suitable for my example - add a
  second light source from the opposite site. So, this is mostly for my
  edification.
- Also, I was using ParametricPlot3D in an earlier
  version and don't remember these issues popping up, but I ended up
  switching to Cylinders because they were simpler in form and faster
  to evaluate.
- Lastly, there's probably more elegant ways than using
  "CylindricalSector3D" (it's a bit on the clunky side), but other
  versions of this ended up using non-circular sectors, so I was looking to 
  build off that

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce your output from `GraphicsRow[MapThread[combinedFeats, opts], ImageSize -> 1300]`. I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYDDi.png). What version of Mathematica and what OS are you using? My screenshot is from 11.3 on Mac.

Comment: Interesting...I'm using 11.1.1 on Windows

Comment: @stallada What is the question?

Comment: [Here's a summary.](https://imgur.com/a/SsAOqpn)

Basically, I have two object definitions (one for a shape, and another corresponding to it's outline) which both seem to work properly when I generate them (via a table) independently.  When I generate them together though, the output has incorrect lighting. Strangely, even combining the two independent graphics with Show yields the same type of issues, but differently. @ChipHurst tried it and it worked for him, so I assume it's some weird issue on my end.

Comment: It could be an OS issue. I don’t have a windows machine to test on, but you might want to try rearranging the order of your graphic primitives. Also see if any [`RenderingOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenderingOptions.html) settings help.

Comment: You could also try `CloudEvaluate[Rasterize[expr, opts]]`. The cloud machines are Linux and they might not have this issue.